# Getting <null> value instead of blank string

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdictionary

When i click on tableview cell it will go to next view and it will display phone and name

```
switch (rowtype) {
    case PhoneRow:
    {
        cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reusableIdentifierNormalCell];
        cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Call %@", nil), self.ecpInfo[@"Name"]];
        cell.subtitleLabel.text = phoneNumber;
        cell.iconImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TelephoneIcon"];
        cell.tag = ECPDetails_RowTagsStart + rowtype;
    }
```

when i execute this line its showing the output like 
 call

Comment: could you be more specific. What do you mean by output like call?

Comment: which value is displaying null?

Comment: Guys, It looks he's new to community, don't down vote.
Let him explain.

Comment: cell.titleLabel.text value is displaying "call <null>" ,  if self.ecpInfo[@"Name"] consists null value.

Comment: what should be displayed if self.ecpInfo[@"Name"] consists null value ?

Comment: if self.ecpInfo[@"Name"] consists null value it should display empty string (" ") or else it should display the name.

Comment: @ZaidPathan  if self.ecpInfo[@"Name"] consists null value it should display empty string (" ") or else it should display the particular name.

Comment: @ArshadShaik Please check updated answer.

Comment: @ZaidPathan Thanks a lot it solved the issue.

Comment: @ArshadShaik Pleasure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one,

Add this macro:

```
#define IS_EMPTY(value) (value == (id)[NSNull null] || value == nil || ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && ([value isEqualToString:@""] ||  [value isEqualToString:@"<null>"]))) ? YES : NO
```

Use it like this:

```
switch (rowtype) {
case PhoneRow:
{

    NSString *name = [NSString new];
     if (!IS_EMPTY(self.ecpInfo[@"Name"])) {
        name =  self.ecpInfo[@"Name”];                  
     }else{
        name = @“”;
     }

    cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reusableIdentifierNormalCell];
    cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Call %@", nil), name];
    cell.subtitleLabel.text = phoneNumber;
    cell.iconImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TelephoneIcon"];
    cell.tag = ECPDetails_RowTagsStart + rowtype;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have null data except when processing data from a server; that's where you should replace it. All the other stuff: Just write string.length == 0.